# Adding a wireless router to a hotel network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

How do I get my Belkin wireless router to give me internet access in a hotel room that has a password for the hotel network from the hardwire in the room...I just want to have more wireless signal in my room that is farther away from the wireless on this floor...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kristian's comments, it's sometimes possible to do this if your router has a setting that tells it always to present the same MAC address. Using the router's MAC address would be best, I think.

Once you set this up, you'd need to connect your computer, use its browser to log in through the hotel's web page.  Doing this while wired to the router might be simplest.  Once logged in, the hotel sees the router's MAC address as the current (authenticated) user regardless of what connects through it, so you should be good to go.

If you've already logged in normally w/o the router in the middle, your computer's MAC address/login will already be associated with the room, so you'd need to wait until the login expires before you set up the router.

Or possibly tell the router to use your computer's MAC address rather than its own, so long as you only intend to hook up the one computer.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to answer your question without knowing the details of the setup.

My immediate answer would be that it is not possible, but if you are keen on doing some testing, then you may be able to get it to work.

If the hotel internet requires you to log in via a web page, then I doubt it will work, but there's a chance it is implemented in the same way that some ISP's do. If this is the case, then I would go about it this way to see if it is possible or not.

1. find the exact model number for your WiFi router look [here](http://www.belkin.com/us/Products/Networking/c/WSNTWLS/) or alternatively look on the label at the bottom/back of your router. Should be something like F9K1123.
2. download the user manual from Belkin website and see if there's an option to add a user name password for the internet part of the setup guide.
3. enter the authentication information you have obtained from the hotel and see if that works.
4. Now try connecting to the WiFi that your router has, documentation for how should be in the manual you downloaded in step 2.

**NOTE:** make sure you connect the cable from the wall to the port marked "WAN" on your router.

Good luck!